# Eclipse Open Type not showing maven path for some classes

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Eclipse Open Type not showing maven path for some classes.

[image]

I am not able to identify the jar from which the class comes from for those files.
What is the setting in eclipse for this?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you find a solution already?

Comment: @Line No luck. But if you select/scroll through the entries, maven path having the jar is shown at the bottom of "Open Type" window. Not able to find a solution to get it displayed in the main "Open Type" window itself.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. For me those entries were not always there, apparently something caused them to show, I'm not sure what :/ Thanks though, please notify me if you get an answer :)